# set_join_field on a Multiple M2M Datamapper relation

Tags: php, orm, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

Please use this question as a start-read; [Multiple M2M in DataMapper ORM issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147998/multiple-m2m-in-datamapper-orm-issue)

What basically happens in that question is that I have issues to store a relationship between 3 Models (tables).

Besides that issue (and that's why I make it a different question) is that I would like to use the `created` field in that table (`dm_entities_userrights_userroles`) too.

So when I would find a solution for the linked issue, that I could also let DataMapper trigger the default action of filling the `created` field on that relation-save too.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? It's kind of hard to figure some DataMapper stuff out, because the documentation doesn't always show (the correct) examples besides the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not. Datamapper doesn't support 3-way relations.

See my reply to your related question (link at the top).